# ValueError: Grouper for not 1-dimensional pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following df:

```
a       b       c   d   e   f
city-1  uc-1    1   1   0   1
city-2  uc-1    0   0   1   0
city-1  uc-2    1   1   1   1
city-2  uc-2    1   0   0   1
```

My code:

```
bnu_u = pd.pivot_table(df,
    index=["a", "b"],
    values=["b", "c", "d", "f"],
    aggfunc={"b":len, "c":np.sum, "d":np.sum, "e":np.sum, "f":np.sum}
)

bnu_u.iloc[:,0] = bnu_u.iloc[:, 0].div(bnu_u.b, axis = 0)
```

This gives me error: `ValueError: Grouper for 'b' not 1-dimensional pivot_table`. Although in another same type of code it is running perfectly.

Comment: The code works very well for me. Will you please send the output of `print(df.head().to_dict)` *before* you run the code?

Comment: Actually, I have a csv file with the data shown in my question. The output you asked for is below. It show NaN although there are values                                             <bound method DataFrame.to_dict of                              q1_1  q2_1  q2_2  q2_3  q3_1  q3_3  q4_1  q4_6  \
town       uc                                                                 
Bakka Khel Sardi Khel         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
Bannu-1    Bazar Ahmad Khan   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN